# Question/Answer previews do not load on network profile activity history

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, activity

Attempting to preview a question or answer from a network profile page's activity tab will indefinitely show a loading animation and will never display the preview. I sat on this page for ~10 minutes to see if it would eventually show up, just in case the act of loading was just *really* slow.

Here's a gif to demonstrate:

[image: Demonstration of network profile not showing question or answer preview]

Using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, reproduced on

- Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (64 bit)
- Microsoft Edge ver. 44.18362.449.0

Opening Chrome's console, I observed the following error when I attempted to preview a post:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> at Object.success (eval at  (jquery.min.js:2), :17:58)
> at i (jquery.min.js:2)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
> at y (jquery.min.js:4)
> at HTMLScriptElement.b.onload.b.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:4)

Could this be fixed?

Comment: |t goes wrong in the AJAX call inside `loadPostBody` to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions/357867?site=meta.stackexchange.com&filter=!7(OijzwQ` as it returns `/**/jQuery112406651785378317274_1607983808578({"error_id":502,"error_message":"too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 38745 seconds","error_name":"throttle_violation"});` and that is not  a response that will make this call `data.items[0].body;`  succeed, as there is no `items` let alone an body at element zero in that array.

Comment: @rene It looks like the main issue there is that it's not using a `key`, so is relying on the quota of 300 daily requests per IP/24 hour period when a `key` is not provided. The error indicates that that quota has been consumed for you, but will be renewed in 10.76 hours. Unfortunately, the issue is complicated due to what appears to be a bug which causes requests which include a `key` to draw down *both* the 10k quota for requests with a `key` *and* the 300 request quota for requests without a key. This will mean that anyone who uses the SE API will have very few non-`key` requests available.